# SQL query to replace multiple occurrences with the most frequent ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-databricks

I have a `products` table, which has the product description in two languages, one in English and one in an alternate language.
Let's say:

| Product_Desc | Product_Desc_Alt |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A2 |
| A | A1 |
| A | A3 |
| B | B1 |
| B | B2 |
| B | B2 |
| C | C1 |

If I do a `GROUP BY` statement, there are multiple alternate language occurrences for the same product. So, let's say:

```sql
SELECT Product_Desc, COUNT(DISTINCT Product_Desc_Alt) AS CNT
FROM products
GROUP BY Product_Desc
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

| Product_Desc | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |

I would like to replace the `Product_Desc_Alt` occurrences with the most frequent ones,
so for example I would like the output to be:

| Product_Desc | Product_Desc_Alt |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A1 |
| A | A1 |
| A | A1 |
| B | B2 |
| B | B2 |
| B | B2 |
| C | C1 |

Obviously, if a product has only one alter lang description, just keep that one.

There may be lots of ways to do that, but I can't think of one.

I am using Azure Databricks so this could also happen with PySpark, but I am interested in doing this the SQL way.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to keep duplicate rows or delete them? If produit x has 4 descriptions `E1, E2, F1, F2` where E is English and F is French to you want to have `E1, F1` , `E1, E1, F1, F1` or `E1, E1, E1, E1`  ?

Comment: The alternate language has only one language, so replace with the most frequent or unique one. I want to keep duplicate rows so let's say for A (product_description) and F1 (alt description). They aren't unique, they have a unique identifier key that I didn't mention for simplicity.

Comment: Does Gert-Jan's answer meet your need?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE products
SET Product_Desc_Alt = (
  SELECT TOP 1 Product_Desc_Alt
  FROM   products P2
  WHERE  P2.Product_Desc = products.Product_Desc
  GROUP BY Product_Desc_Alt
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
```